# Issue with JPA Sub Query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I start using `QueryDsl 4` And I got this error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPASubQuery.iterate(JPASubQuery.java:72)
    at com.querydsl.core.support.FetchableQueryBase.fetch(FetchableQueryBase.java:46)
    at dao.SearchProjetDao.getListProjetsQueryDsl(SearchProjetDao.java:108)
    at controllers.ProjetRest.getListProjetsQueryDsl(ProjetRest.java:82)
```

When I try this sub query

```
QProjet prj = new QProjet("prj");
...
BooleanBuilder where_loc = new BooleanBuilder();

if( bean.commune != null ){

    QLocalisation loc_2 = new QLocalisation("loc_2");

    where_loc.and(prj.id.in( 
            JPAExpressions.select(loc_2.projet.id).from(loc_2)
            .where(loc_2.commune.id.eq(bean.commune))
            .fetch()
    ));

}
...
```

I used to use `JPASubQuery` in `QueryDsl 3` but it do not exist anymore in version 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed fetch in the wrong place.

```
where_loc.and(prj.id.in( 
            JPAExpressions.select(loc_2.projet.id).from(loc_2)
            .where(loc_2.commune.id.eq(bean.commune))
         //   .fetch()  <--- Remove
    ));
```

in expects either (among other)

- `SubQueryExpression` - the overload picked by modified code
- `Collection` - the overload picked by buggy code. (I assume these should be constants)

See [Subquery Examples in QueryDls4 doc](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.2.1/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e410)

Comment: Updated the answer with the name if the correct jar.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-jpa/4.2.1
Fully qualified path is `com.querydsl.jpa.JPASubQuery`

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: thank you @Lesiak it work now ... just delete the wrong answer to not confuse people